# SQL Where clause greatly increases query time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a table that I do some joins and operations on. This table has about 150,000 rows and if I select all and run it, it returns in about 10 seconds. If I create my query into its own table, and filter out all the rows where a certain field is null, now the query takes 10 minutes to run. Is it suppoused to be like this or is there any way to fix it? Here is the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    Select 
     I.Date_Created
    ,I.Company_Code
    ,I.Division_Code
    ,I.Invoice_Number
    ,Sh.CUST_PO
    ,I.Total_Quantity
    ,ID.Total
    ,SH.Ship_City City
    ,CASE WHEN SH.Ship_Cntry <> 'US' THEN 'INT' ELSE SH.Ship_prov END State
    ,SH.Ship_Zip Zip
    ,SH.Ship_Cntry Country
    ,S.CustomerEmail
    from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I (nolock)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    ID.Company_Code
                    ,ID.Division_Code
                    ,ID.Invoice_Number
                    ,SUM (ID.Price* ID.Quantity) Total
                    FROM [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Detail ID (nolock)
                    GROUP BY ID.Company_Code, ID.Division_Code, ID.Invoice_Number) ID 
            ON I.Company_Code = ID.Company_Code
            AND I.Division_Code = ID.Division_Code
            AND I.Invoice_Number = ID.Invoice_Number
    LEFT JOIN 
        [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST SH (nolock) ON I.Pickticket_Number = SH.Packslip
    LEFT JOIN 
        [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[MagentoCustomerEmailData] S on SH.CUST_PO = S.InvoiceNumber

    Where I.Company_Code ='09' AND I.Division_Code = '001'
    AND I.Customer_Number = 'ECOM2X'
    )T
    Where T.CustomerEmail IS NOT NULL -- This is the problematic line
Order By T.Date_Created desc
```

Comment: "I have a table that I do some joins and operations on."  You seem to have many tables and many operations.  It is unclear what exactly you are asking, but if I had to guess, if you looked at the intermediate table, it would be really, really big.

Comment: If you use SSMS, right click on the query and check Show Actual Execution Plan. Then run the query. The execution plan display may recommend an index to be added to a table.

Comment: Which server is the query running from? [JMNYC-AMTDB] or [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL]. I would normally avoid joining tables across linked servers. Is this necessary? You are dealing with two different query optimizers on two different servers. Can you get the data together one server first? Without the problematic line, the servers just need to return all rows. when you introduced the problematic line, you are now asking two different SQL Server optimizers (on two different servers) to create an efficient plan. I dont even think SQL Server will do that, let alone could I tell you how it does it if it did

Comment: @jamie, unfortunately, the linker servers is necessary. I am running out of the JMDNJ database. What is the best way to move forward? Maybe create a new table out of me result (it will be static) and then add that table to the main table I am working with (not pictured)

Comment: If the query is running fine without the problematic line, then add a step. Get your results into a table without the problematic line then query that new table and add your problematic filter there. That will work, and should be sufficient if this is a one time/adhoc request. If this is gonna be operational, there is much more to address.

Comment: Ideally you filter in the inner-most query if you write queries like that.  Is there anything stopping you from keeping the where clause conditions together?  Also S.CustomerEmail is NULL in two cases: 1) left join returns nulls on non-match conditions or 2) that date column accepts nulls... so it might be preferable to do an inner join on the S-aliased table with additionally: S.CustomerEmail IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aware of the [Index Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017) and you are sure about the problem point, then you can use this to improve it:

```
USE A1WAREHOUSE;
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MagentoCustomerEmailData_CustomerEmail
ON [dbo].[MagentoCustomerEmailData] (CustomerEmail ASC);

GO
```

Totally, you need to add index on columns used in `ORDER BY`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ON` etc sections. Before adding indexes be sure that you are aware of the consequences.

Read more about Index:

1. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9133/sql-server-nonclustered-indexes/
2. https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/indexing-dos-and-don-ts